# nano will not work in chroot folder

Tags: xterm, chroot, nano

I run a chroot on a /var/www/ everything is OK but nano wont work

I copied it's binary to /var/www/bin and libreries to /var/www/lib

but when nano some file i got this error :

```
Error opening terminal: xterm.
```

What should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a hunch but try running `which xterm` outside of the chroot and make sure that binary is accessible inside the chroot.

For example, on my Mac the path is:

```
bash-4.3$ which xterm
/opt/X11/bin/xterm
```

Comment: ok , which didn't show anything but locate worked. I copied all directories to mysq chroot folder and then nano works

Comment: @esxzawq Click the checkmark on the left of this post if it answered your question.